# form with id attribute and input with form attribute ie11 issue

Tags: forms, input, internet-explorer-11

This only happens in ie11, this works fine in chrome and ie8

I have code programmed like this

```
<form .... id='mainform'>
<table>...</>
....
<button>....
....
</form>
<input form='mainform' ... >...
```

The `<input>` is outside the `<form>` tags but it works except in ie11

unless i put the `<input>` before the `</form>` then it works in ie11

the odd thing is in ie11 when i use developer tools it moves the `</form>` so the input comes after the `</form>` except it works, but if i change the code to match what the developer tools says it fails

What am I doing wrong? why wont ie11 have a `<form>` with an id attribute accept `<input>` with a form attribute the same as the form id?

Comment: When it fails all required data is submitted except that of the `<input>` located outside the `</form>` These `<input>` are type radio located in a table, when I have the source code configured in such a way that it works in ie11 it will fail the same way if I enable tablesorter

Comment: Here is an example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chris123/t4zd3p2b/2/) that works in chrome but not in ie11. Changing form1 will break it in chrome moving the input inside the form tags will make it work in ie11

Comment: Would something like this work?

`$('#button').mouseenter(function () {
    $('#inside').val($('#mytable').find('input:checked').val());`

Comment: The above does solve the problem of having inputs outside of a form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of note, Internet Explorer up-to-and-including version 11 does not currently support using the `form=""` attribute on `<input />` elements located outside of a `<form>` element.

As for the F12 issue, that looks like a bug. I'll let the team know.

Disclaimer: I work on Internet Explorer

**Update** I've made a copy of your jsFiddle with the extra `<html>` etc elements removed: http://jsfiddle.net/chris123/t4zd3p2b/2/ however I cannot reproduce the "moving `</form>`" tag bug. Do you have precise reproduction steps?

Comment: I suspect that its just correcting how the bad code is suppose to "look" but doesnt actually change its functionality

try 
    <table>
    <form>
    </table>
    </form>