# using an input file element inside a different form

Tags: javascript, html, http, dom

I have an IE specific problem.
It happens in the latest version of IE as well as former versions.
I have an input file inside a form. 
Now, that form, is not the form which this input belongs to because I'm using a different form (attached to the body) as the form for the input file so I could send it.
I set the "form" attribute for that input.
I don't see the file being sent. The content-Length is small (49). 
I compared it to chrom or FF and it works fine.
I'm getting that specific form in my JS code and then submitting it.

Has anybody encountered this situation?
It seems that even though I'm setting the form id to the input, it doesn't work.

Comment: *"latest version of IE"* So IE11 running in IE11 mode?

Comment: I edited the post - IE11 and below

Comment: IE doesn't support the form attribute yet.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26380551/form-with-id-attribute-and-input-with-form-attribute-ie11-issue

Comment: @Quentin According to API it does https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

Comment: @OddDev `<form>` does not equal `<input form="xxx" />`. The OP is asking about the html5 form attribute.

Comment: @epascarello How do you know?

Comment: I see now. thanks Quentin

Comment: @OddDev Did you not read *I set the "form" attribute*? I sure hope IE supports the form tag. :)

Comment: @OddDev — [the attributes of form controls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#Browser_compatibility) has `form` marked with a `?` for IE (meaning "the earlier version of IE to support this is unknown", which means not currently supported).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form attribute does not work in IE http://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html_form_attributes.asp
What you can do is "wrap" your inputs with the form to have a cross-browser solution.
If your inputs are scattered this won't work thought so you must attach the form in an upper level of the document hierarchy.